# Fail to validate URL in Facebook webhook subscription with python flask on the back end and ssl

Tags: python, facebook, ssl, flask

I'm trying to start using new messenger platform from FB.
So i have server with name (i.e.)  www.mysite.com
I got a valid SSL certificate for that domain and apache is setup correctly - all good.

I have a python code on my server which runs flask and i point it to these certificates I got for the server:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from pymessenger.bot import Bot
import requests
import ipdb
from OpenSSL import SSL
app = Flask(__name__)
TOKEN = "<access_token>"
bot = Bot(TOKEN)

@app.route("/webhook", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def hello():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if (request.args.get("hub.verify_token") == "my_awesome_token"):
                return request.args.get("hub.challenge")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        output = request.json
        event = output['entry'][0]['messaging']
        for x in event:
            if (x.get('message') and x['message'].get('text')):
                message = x['message']['text']
                recipient_id = x['sender']['id']
                bot.send_text_message(recipient_id, message)
            else:
                pass
        return "success"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # tried this - no luck
    #context = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv23_METHOD)
    #context.use_privatekey_file('/home/mysite.com.key')
    #context.use_certificate_file('/home/intermediate.crt')

    # tried this - also same result
    context = ('/mysite.com.crt', '/mysite.com.key')

    app.run(host='www.mysite.com',port=5002, debug=True, ssl_context=context)
```

It starts without error and if I navigate with my browser - i see it gets connections.

[image]

port 5002 is open inf my firewall.

But when I go to FB and try to subscribe to that URL - it keeps failing with this error:

[image]

```
The URL couldn't be validated. 
Callback verification failed with the following errors: curl_errno = 60;
curl_error = SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate;
HTTP Status Code = 200; 
HTTP Message = Connection established
```

I've read half the internet on the possible reasons and saw many different suggestions, but I can't make any of those work - i end up with the same result 95% of the time. 5% - some other error due to Flask bugging out with some "crazy" settings I try.

What can be wrong? I'm using certificate files which I got from COMODO.
Also tried in the call back url to use `/webhook` - no luck either. same error.

Comment: You are missing some intermediate certificate along the chain, so the chain is not complete, and the remote server can not successfully validate your certificate. You need to put those intermediate certificates on your server as well. Check with Comodo for which ones you need and how to get them, https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/List/Index/75/instantsslenterprisesslintranetssl

Comment: @CBroe chatting with Comodo guys - not much help. I followed your link - i see some certificates for download. so bassically i need one of those? if I have it - what do I do with it? (sorry - i'm totally new to ssl).
UPD: They got me a link to the file!:) https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/979/108/domain-validation-sha-2

the 4.07kb is the one as they say. What do I do with it?

Comment: Ok I concatenated this downloaded bundle into CRT - used that with falsk = WORKS!!!

THANK YOU!

Comment: You need to put it on your server, in the same directory where your main certificate is placed. (Not sure if you need to register it somewhere too, or put the path to it into the config somewhere – check with your server admin.)

Comment: @GeekSince1982 can you tell me how you bundle them? Can you explain a bit? I have the same issue, I got 2 .crt files ( one is big, other is small) from godaddy and I renamed my .pem file that was generated via openssl command to .key and I was using those 2 files for ssl. Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever manage to get this sorted? I'm sure there are others who might like to know what the issue was and how you finally fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the answer above, the issue is that you do not have the issuer certificate which means that a secure connection can not be established. These certificates can be downloaded from your certificate provider, in your case Comodo. Once you have them you need to serve both to the user so a SSL connection can be established. There are multiple ways to do depending on how you are hosting but the easiest way to do it is to concat the certificates together. The order they are concated in IS important and will cause a Key Mismatch error if done in the incorrect order. Your certificate should be first, followed by the issuer certificate and the root certificate, like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
(Your Primary SSL certificate: your_domain_name.crt)
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
(Your Intermediate certificate: Intermediate.crt)
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
(Your Root certificate: TrustedRoot.crt)
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

This can easily be done from the CLI like this:

```
cat your_domain_name.crt Intermediate.crt TrustedRoot.crt > combined.crt
```

This command combines the 3 files in the proper order and stores the output in a new file called `combined.crt`.
 See [here](https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/pem-ssl-creation.htm) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Add the issuer certificate also. Comodo will issue their own certificate. YOu need to include that while starting the server.

Answer (score 0):

I use certbot and Let's Encrypt.

Follow Installing Client software.

Then run command => sudo ./certbot-auto --apache -d YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME.COM (i tried apache, nginx and flask alone, all works, no need to put https at front)

cd /etc/letsencrypt/live/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME.COM/

context = ('/etc/letsencrypt/live/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME.COM/fullchain.pem', '/etc/letsencrypt/live/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME.COM/privkey.pem')

i used cert.pem instead of fullchain.pem at first and got the above error, succeed after changed cert.pem to fullchain.pem